# Visual Studio doesn't find Class to test in Unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

The unit test I'm trying to write doesn't show the Classes that I need to test.

In the first picture you can see that I have the project with the classes referenced.

In the second picture you can see that I try to type the class but visual studio doesn't recognize it.

[image]

[image: Solution view]

Comment: What if you start with `ConsoleApplication1.` - have you imported the namespace?

Comment: What @JamesThorpe said. Not to mention, you won't see `Program` popup even with `ConsoleApplication1.` if your `Program` class is not set to `public`